# VBA problems with html extraction

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code here for getting the info from a table in a website into a spread in VBA Excel.Here is the Url
     http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id=1

The idea is to loop through the ID's to downlaod the profiles onto the sheet.
The program uses the underlying HTML code from the site.The code seems to work well to a point but my poorish understanding of HTML could be the problem
So far I have succeeded in downloading the following fields.
dogName,dateofbirth,trainerName,date(race),track,dis,fin,pos,split,remarks,time..
the fields I am having difficulty with are trp,by,win/sec,going,price,grd and calc
Below is the field name with the corresponding HTML from the site:These are the fields I can't retrieve:

```
trp                <td class="center">[2]</td>
by                 <td>12<td>
going              <td class="center">+10</td>
price              <td class="center">5/1</td>
grd                <td class="center">A2</td> 
calc               <td class="center">24.01</td> 

 win/sec is a href link
 <a href="http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id=39894" onclick="return Html.popup(this, {width:800, height:480})" title="Click for Dog Form...">KAL RY TAZ</a>
```

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
 Sub GetTrackData()
    Dim response As String
    Dim dogHomeUrl As String
    Dim dogFormUrl As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim dogName As String
    Dim dogDate As String
    Dim trainer As String
    Dim breeding As String

Dim loc1 As Long, loc2 As Long

dogHomeUrl = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id="
dogFormUrl = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_form.sd?dog_id="
x = 2
For i = 1 To 7
    response = XmlHttpRequest(dogHomeUrl & i)
    Debug.Print (response)

    loc1 = InStr(response, "popUpHead")
    loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, "<h1>") + 4
    loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</h1>")


    dogName = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

    If dogName <> "" Then
        'this is the code that hgets the data from the top of the page
        loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<li>")
        loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, "(") + 1
        loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, ")")
        dogDate = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

        loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<strong>Trainer</strong>") + 24
        loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</li>")
        trainer = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
        response = XmlHttpRequest(dogFormUrl & i)




        loc1 = InStr(response, "Full Results")
        Do While (loc1 <> 0)
            Dim raceDate As String
            Dim raceTrack As String
            Dim raceDis As String
            Dim raceTrp As String
            Dim raceSplit As String
            Dim raceFin As String
            Dim raceBy As String
            Dim racePos As String
            Dim raceRemarks As String
            Dim raceWinSec As String
            Dim raceTime As String
            Dim raceGoing As String
            Dim racePrice As String
            Dim raceGrd As String
            Dim raceCalc As String

            'next is the code I have used to extract the fields
            'so far I have managed the 8 field below out of the table
            'having already got dogname,date and trainer above.
            'I have tried different variations of these code block 
            ' but I think my grasp of html is not sufficent to crack it
            'any help appreciated.  


            'this is the code that gets the data from the  table
            loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, ">") + 1
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</a>")
            raceDate = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
            raceTrack = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 25
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>") - 7
            raceDis = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

           loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
           loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
           racePos = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

           loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
           loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
           raceSplit = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

           loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 25
           loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>") - 7
           raceFin = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))


          loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "i>") + 2
          loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</i>")
          raceRemarks = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))


         loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 24
           loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>") - 7
           racePrice = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))




            Range("A" & x).Value = dogName
            Range("B" & x).Value = dogDate
            Range("C" & x).Value = trainer
            Range("D" & x).Value = raceDate
            Range("E" & x).Value = raceTrack
            Range("F" & x).Value = raceDis
            Range("G" & x).Value = raceTrp
            Range("H" & x).Value = raceFin
            Range("I" & x).Value = raceSplit
            Range("J" & x).Value = raceWinSec
            Range("K" & x).Value = racePos
            Range("L" & x).Value = raceRemarks
            Range("M" & x).Value = raceGoing
            Range("N" & x).Value = raceTime
            Range("O" & x).Value = raceBy
            Range("M" & x).Value = racePrice
            Range("N" & x).Value = raceGrd
            Range("O" & x).Value = raceCalc







            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "Full Results")
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        Debug.Print (response)
    End If


    Next i
End Sub
Function XmlHttpRequest(url As String) As String
    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", url, False
    xml.send
    XmlHttpRequest = xml.responseText
 End Function
```

Any help greatly appreciated
Colin(jimmy)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205442/excel-vba-get-inner-text-of-html-table-td    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095050/vba-spliting-results-from-html-imported-table-into-excel   http://officetricks.com/download-html-table-to-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Excel can get it's own web pages, your help not required.

Stick each page onto a blank sheet and refer to the cells on your main sheet.

**Alt + D**(ata), Get External )**D**(ata), (New )**W**(eb Query) specifies the parameters.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply what you suggest is  almost the manual way of getting the data,I am looking for an automated way hence all the code.Web queries are unreliable on many sites.regards Colin