# Extracting table from Html by class

Tags: html, vba, excel, html-table

I tried to solve my problem using many Subs/Functions. I am looking for a solution as how to extract a table from HTML->URL - by it class tag when the table on that page doesn't mention name or id's tags.

Source  html: www.nbp.pl/home.aspx?f=/kursy/kursya.html
https://d3higte790sj35.cloudfront.net/images/mg/xq/f16c888645b8ce4212b641de2441c7aa.jpeg

[VBA spliting results from html imported table into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095050/vba-spliting-results-from-html-imported-table-into-excel)
[Excel VBA: get content from online HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141394/excel-vba-get-content-from-online-html-table)

And the others...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim tbls, tbl, trs, tr, tds, td, r, c

    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    IE.Navigate "www.nbp.pl/home.aspx?f=/kursy/kursya.html"

    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set tbls = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")

    Set tbl = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(31)
    Set trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")

    For r = 0 To trs.Length - 1
        Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("td")
        'if no <td> then look for <th>
        If tds.Length = 0 Then Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("th")

        For c = 0 To tds.Length - 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Offset(r, c).Value = tds(c).innerText
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

This code will give you `Tabela nr 103/A/NBP/2016 z dnia 2016-05-31` table from the link as you've shown in the image. Table will be displayed from `Cell A2`.

This is same code that @TimWilliams answered to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095050/vba-spliting-results-from-html-imported-table-into-excel) mentioned by you in question.

Comment: Thank you alot, but i dont get the "," character  in few numbers. :3

Comment: @R.Michael Are you talking about `Kurs średni` column. Is there any specific row?

Comment: yes im talking about that. @mrig

Btw. i tried on other page, i just pick by number 20 table on page then tried scrap it. Cant write code cause it's to many character in post (LOL) 
site: https://www.kraken.com/charts
changed: 

Line 14to:     Set tbl = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(20)

and  get error at Line15.

Comment: @R.Michael - Okay give me some time, will look into it.

Comment: @R.Michael - No, I am just another member on SO like you.

Comment: @R.Michael - I've edited me code, try now, should work.

Comment: Same problem ( old picture but same error ) http://scr.hu/0q3mv/v8kje

i think it's problem of lag between me and srv. Because page loading 3s and data fill table/loads in 7s so yeah. Maybe because of that? I just use old one, and edit

Answer (score 0):

Code and new page i was talking about under your post.

`Sub Kraken()

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim tbls, tbl, trs, tr, tds, td, r, c

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.Navigate "https://www.kraken.com/charts"

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

Set tbls = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")

Set tbl = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(20)
Set trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")

For r = 0 To trs.Length - 1
    Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("td")
    'if no <td> then look for <th>
    If tds.Length = 0 Then Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("th")

    For c = 0 To tds.Length - 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("J1").Offset(r, c).Value = tds(c).innerText
    Next c
Next r
```

End Sub
'DataTables_Table_1`